# Setting custom messages in my macro depending on the error type

Tags: vba

So depending on the conditions my "ChangeDate" value may show #Value.  So when that happens and the user clicks the Calibration button i want an error message to show up.  Why is my code not working?  do i have to do something before the GoalSeek code runs?

```
        Sub CIGSCalib()

        Set Targetdate = Range("Update_CIGS_TargetDate")
        Set TargetCIGS = Range("Update_CIGS_TargetValue")
        Set ChangeDate = Range("Calib_CIGS_DV")

        Sheets("profiles and sequencing").Activate

        Range("A1").Offset(Targetdate - 1, 3).GoalSeek _
            Goal:=TargetCIGS, _
            ChangingCell:=Range("A1").Offset(ChangeDate - 1, 2)

        Sheets("Inputs").Activate

        On Error GoTo ErrMSg
        Exit Sub
        ErrMSg:
        MsgBox ("No Calibration Needed")
```

Edit:  i forgot to mention that when the ChangeDate = #Value i get this error code "run time 13 Type mismatch" and it bombs out at the GoalSeek code section

Comment: Put an exit sub right before errmsg label.

Comment: Good catch, but still bombs at the GoalSeek section :(

Comment: Try Range("Calib_CIGS_DV").value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
On Error GoTo ErrMSg
```

needs to be declare before the error happens, so place it after your sets and dims

Comment: I'd put the `on error` statement right at the beginning of the sub/function, just to be sure ;)

Comment: That works well too, just my practice i like to put dims / sub at the very beginning, maybe it's not a good practice?

Comment: if you put the `on error` statement at the beginning of the sub/function, you'll catch *all and every* error raised by the code. if you have more than one type of error in your code, you should write your error handler appropriately to handle each error code separatedly (maybe with a `select case`  statement). It's just a matter of preference. If you put the `on error` just above the line that is prone to raise an error, you won't catch any errors raised before it.

Comment: I stand corrected.  OP please put the line from my answer as Barranka described

Comment: this worked perfectly.  thanks for the tip Alex and Barranka.  Man i wish i could buy y'all a beer or something.